# Simple Finite State Machine using templates

Tags: c++, state-machine

I'm having a go at a very simple FSM with actions at entry and exit. Popular(?) examples pass around raw pointers and use manual resource management (e.g. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state/cpp/example)

My goal was using automated resource management and a simple interface. As such I tried using templates. It works and the interface is ok-ish

```cpp
class Fsm;

class State {
public:
    virtual ~State() = default;

    void SetFsm(Fsm* fsm) { fsm_ = fsm; }
    virtual void Enter() = 0;
    virtual void Exit() = 0;
protected:
    // to allow state changes
    Fsm* fsm_{ nullptr };
};

class Fsm {
public:
    template <class T>
    void TransitionTo() {
        if (state_ != nullptr) {
            // if switching to same state, do nothing
            const auto temp = std::make_unique<T>();
            if (dynamic_cast<T*>(state_.get()) != nullptr) { return; }
            state_->Exit();
        }
        state_ = std::make_unique<T>();
        state_->SetFsm(this);
        state_->Enter();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<State> state_;
};
```

After defining `class MyState1` and `class MyState2` this can then be called as

```cpp
const auto my_object = std::make_unique<Fsm>();
my_object->TransitionTo<MyState1>();
my_object->TransitionTo<MyState2>()
```

But it doesn't allow a state the be passed at construction as templated constructors aren't a thing. So I created this constructor

```cpp
Fsm(std::unique_ptr<State> state = nullptr) : state_(std::move(state)) {}
```

But that results in this

```cpp
const auto my_object = std::make_unique<Fsm>(std::make_unique<MyState1>());
```

Any suggestions how to make this a simpler constructor? And any general remarks on using templates for this task?

Comment: Cannot `my_object` be a normal variable of automatic lifetime? Why is `make_unique` used to create it? States have to be pointers (in your case at least), but why make the whole state machine a pointer?

Comment: What you mean by "templated constructors aren't a thing"?

Comment: @RuhRohRaggy
```template <class T>
Fsm() : state_(nullptr){
    TransitionTo<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If interface and readability is your only concern and you want to get rid of writing long lines of nested functions you can simply implement the factory pattern.

For example:

```
class Fsm 
{
    public:
        class factory
        {
            public:
                template <typename T, typename... Args>
                static std::unique_ptr<Fsm> create(Args&&... args)
                {
                    auto fsm_ptr = new Fsm(std::make_unique<T>( std::forward<Args>(args)... ));
                    return std::unique_ptr<Fsm>( fsm_ptr );
                }
        };
        
        // DONT FORGET FRIEND CLASS
        friend class factory;
        
    // MAKE CONSTRUCTOR PRIVATE
    private:
        Fsm(std::unique_ptr<State> state = nullptr) : state_(std::move(state)) {}
        
}
```

And since now you cannot create Fsm class directly, you are forced to use the factory with a simpler/intuitive interface.

```
auto obj = Fsm::factory::create<MyState1>();
obj->TransitionTo<MyState2>();
```

And it will also let you pass additional arguments to build your State class e.g

```
auto obj = Fsm::factory::create<MyState1>(1, "context", 2.0f);
```

=====

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class Fsm;

class State {
public:
    virtual ~State() = default;

    void SetFsm(Fsm* fsm) { fsm_ = fsm; }
    virtual void Enter() = 0;
    virtual void Exit() = 0;
protected:
    // to allow state changes
    Fsm* fsm_{ nullptr };
};

class MyState1 : public State
{
    public:
        MyState1(){};
        virtual void Enter() override {};
        virtual void Exit() override {};
};

class MyState2 : public State
{
    public:
        MyState2(){};
        virtual void Enter() override {};
        virtual void Exit() override {};
};

class Fsm 
{
    public:
        class factory
        {
            public:
                template <typename T, typename... Args>
                static std::unique_ptr<Fsm> create(Args&&... args)
                {
                    auto fsm_ptr = new Fsm(std::make_unique<T>( std::forward<Args>(args)... ));
                    return std::unique_ptr<Fsm>( fsm_ptr );
                }
        };
        
        friend class factory;
        
    private:
        Fsm(std::unique_ptr<State> state = nullptr) : state_(std::move(state)) {}
        
    public:
        template <class T>
        void TransitionTo() {
            if (state_ != nullptr) {
                // if switching to same state, do nothing
                const auto temp = std::make_unique<T>();
                if (dynamic_cast<T*>(state_.get()) != nullptr) { return; }
                state_->Exit();
            }
            state_ = std::make_unique<T>();
            state_->SetFsm(this);
            state_->Enter();
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<State> state_;
};

int main()
{
    auto obj = Fsm::factory::create<MyState1>();
    obj->TransitionTo<MyState2>();

    return 0;
}
```